# Access Grails associated domain classes in controller or view?

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, grails-orm

Given a domain class with a number of fields referencing other domain classes, is it considered best practice to access the fields in the controller, adding them to the model, or to access the fields directly in the view?

In other words, is a small model better than a simple view or vice versa?

For Example:

```
// Controller
render(view: 'index', model: [b: a.b, c:a.b.c])

// View
${a}, ${c}, ${c.id}
```

Vs.

```
// Controller
render(view: 'index', model: [a: a])

// View
${a.b}, ${a.b.c}, ${a.b.c.id}
```

Also, do these alternatives have performance implications in Grails / GORM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's entirely dependent on the organization of your usage, but generally I try to keep the count of entries in my model small for each render call.

If you have a part of the page that needs to display parts of a, a.b, and a.b.c, then passing them in as a single reference to "a" seems fine.

If you have different parts of the page you're displaying, one section refers to a, another to a.b, and another to a.b.c, then I would suggest you look up Templating (http://www.slideshare.net/laelfrog/grails-layouts-sitemesh), and pass the "a" into the top section, and pass "a.b" from that top-level page into the section template that uses a.b as "b", etc.

so if your controller has:

```
render( view: 'index', model: [a:a] )
```

index.gsp might look like:

```
<g:render template="toplevel" model="[a: a]" />
<g:render template="midlevel" model="[b: a.b]" />
<g:render template="bottomlevel" model="[c: a.b.c]" />
```

Then, in template _toplevel, you can use "a" (actually, for this level passing the model is superfluous, as the current model is the same as what the controller sent in).

But in _midlevel, you'd be able to access "a.b" as just "b", and in _bottomlevel, you could access a.b.c as "c".   Each template should know about what it needs to, and should really have it's own names for those things, rather than relying on a model from 2 renders up the chain.

As far as optimization goes, I doubt it's an issue, unless you're re-doing a lot of work over and over again to build your model.  Just de-referencing children is not really a problem.

Comment: I like the template / model pattern you suggest. Re: performance I am fairly certain that there is no difference between the same code in a controller / service and in a view. That said there can definitely be issues calling `a.b` (or especially `a.bees`) many times depending on the particular domain relations in which case we should probably memoize the field access in the controller.